# Zend Registry not working

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have following code in my bootstrap

```
protected function _userSession(){
    $session=new Zend_Session_Namespace("userIdentity");
    $session->greet="Hello!!!!!";
    Zend_Registry::set("session", $session);        
}
```

And in controller I write:

```
public function index() {
    $session = Zend_Registry::get("session");
    echo $session->greet;        
}
```

But it will showing the error message like: No entry is registered for key 'session'. Whats wrong with this code. Any solution.

Comment: Do you to prefix with _initUserSession for it to be called? Or do you call it in the bootstrap in another function?

Comment: I create the _userSession function in bootstrap but not prefix it with _init

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to change the bootstrap method for user session to `_initUserSession()`

Depending on how you set things up, the bootstrap will automatically call all methods that start with `_init`

See here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.theory-of-operation.html#zend.application.theory-of-operation.bootstrap.resource-methods

If you have the default `index.php` used by zend, then your bootstrap will automatically call all methods that start with `_init`

So if you have something like the following:

`$application->bootstrap()->run();`

But if you do something like this:

```
$application->bootstrap(array(
    'FrontController',
    'Layout',
    'View',
    'Db'))->run();
```

The above will only call the init methods for the ones listed in your array.